# Single quote in a query

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I insert an single quotes in a query ?

**Example**

```
select *, 'INSERT INTO San_Endereco (Endereco_Id, Logradouro_Id, Bairro_Id, CEP, Logradouro, Livre) VALUES 
(' + CAST(Endereco_Id as varchar) + ','
+ CAST(Logradouro_Id as varchar) + ','
+ CAST(Bairro_Id as varchar) + ','
+ CAST (CEP as varchar) + ','
+ CAST(Logradouro as varchar) + ','
+ CAST(Livre as varchar) + ')'  as teste
FROM San_Endereco
```

Before each `CAST` I need put the single quote. How can I do that ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use two single quotes: `''`

```
select *, 'INSERT INTO San_Endereco (Endereco_Id, Logradouro_Id, Bairro_Id, CEP, Logradouro, Livre) VALUES  
(''' + CAST(Endereco_Id as varchar) + ''',''' 
+ CAST(Logradouro_Id as varchar) + ''',''' 
+ CAST(Bairro_Id as varchar) + ''',''' 
+ CAST (CEP as varchar) + ''',''' 
+ CAST(Logradouro as varchar) + ''',''' 
+ CAST(Livre as varchar) + ''')'''  as teste 
FROM San_Endereco
```

Answer (score 2):

Use double single quotes `''`

If a single quote is contained in the actual data to be inserted, the command often becomes corrupted. To solve the problem, simply replace any single quote with two quotes (not the double quote character but two single-quote characters).

Comment: -1: Link only answers should not be posted. Post a comment instead. Links go dead and than your answer is worthles.

Comment: Edited my answer. Thank you for your explanation in why my post was bad :)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @var varchar(100)
select @var = 'txt'        
select char(39)+@var+char(39) -- with single quote
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, 'INSERT INTO San_Endereco (Endereco_Id, Logradouro_Id, Bairro_Id, CEP, Logradouro, Livre) VALUES 
        (''' + CAST(Endereco_Id as varchar) + ''','
    + ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `'` in string two times:

```
declare @var varchar(100)
select @var = 'txt'        
select ' '+@var+' ' -- without single quote
select ''''+@var+'''' -- with single quote
```